# Randomizing a list in Python

Tags: python, list, random

I am wondering if there is a good way to "shake up" a list of items in Python. For example `[1,2,3,4,5]` might get shaken up / randomized to `[3,1,4,2,5]` (any ordering equally likely).

Answer (score 44, accepted):

```
from random import shuffle

list1 = [1,2,3,4,5]
shuffle(list1)

print list1
---> [3, 1, 2, 4, 5]
```

Answer (score 4):

Use `random.shuffle`:

```
>>> import random
>>> l = [1,2,3,4]
>>> random.shuffle(l)
>>> l
[3, 2, 4, 1]
```

> **[random.shuffle(x[, random])](https://docs.python.org/2/library/random.html#random.shuffle)**
>
> Shuffle the sequence x in place. The optional argument random is a
>   0-argument function returning a random float in [0.0, 1.0); by
>   default, this is the function random().

Answer (score 2):

[random.shuffle](https://docs.python.org/2/library/random.html#random.shuffle) it!

```
In [8]: import random

In [9]: l = [1,2,3,4,5]

In [10]: random.shuffle(l)

In [11]: l
Out[11]: [5, 2, 3, 1, 4]
```