# How to get an unsorted range in Python

Tags: python, list, random

I have a list here

```
List = ['first', 'second', 'third', 'fourth', 'etc']
```

How can I loop through `List` randomly with random indices and print each item in the random index. For example I want the output to look something like this:

> Output:
>
> ```
> fourth
> first
> etc
> third
> second
> ```

Comment: Shuffle the list?

Comment: @jonrsharpe What if I want to shuffle the range()?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Randomizing a list in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34862378/randomizing-a-list-in-python)

Comment: @ArkistarvhKltzuonstev Is there a way to randomize the range()?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to do this without mutating the original list, you can use `random.sample`:

```
>>> import random
>>>
>>> items = ['first', 'second', 'third', 'fourth', 'etc']
>>> print("\n".join(random.sample(items, len(items))))
fourth
second
third
etc
first
```

Also, get in the habit of giving your variables lowercase names that don't conflict with built-in functions or types!  :)

Comment: It worked. Thank You. random.sample(range(), len(range()) worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

You can randomize the list like this:

```py
import random

List = ['first', 'second', 'third', 'fourth', 'etc']
for i in random.shuffle(List):
    print(i)
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use **random.shuffle**

```
import random
List = ['first', 'second', 'third', 'fourth', 'etc']
random.shuffle(List)
print(List)
```

hope that's what you were looking for